# How to get the full list of applications like in control panel

Tags: windows, powershell, shell

I have been stuck at this stage of my little project.
What I try to do is list the applications that are installed and choose one of the apps to uninstall, the issue I have is that not all the apps appear, so I can't select them. For example Google chrome is not appearing while I'm using it right now to write this question.

I use this function to get all the apps:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-Object -Property Name | Out-GridView -Title "All apps on destination Computer"
```

and this is whole script:

```
    $ComputerName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the computer name' # the name of the computer to remove the app from

Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-Object -Property Name | Out-GridView -Title "All apps on destination Computer"

$Name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input name of the application (has to be exact name)'  #name of the application
$Application = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -ComputerName $ComputerName | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $Name}  #choose the object, this will be the app that we will delete
if ($Application) {
  $Application.Uninstall()
  "The removal was successful"
}
else {
  $Name + ' is not installed on ' + $ComputerName
}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
```

I'm not that good with PowerShell so excuse me if this is a stupid question

Comment: I will try Get-package but it seems it doesn't have remote option

Comment: The reliable source for this is the registry, i.e.: `Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Or get-package, which should be faster.  Uninstall-package only works on msi providers.  Powershell 5.1 only.  Metadata['uninstallstring'] has the uninstall string for Programs providers. It can take wildcards and arrays as arguments.  Install-package works with msi files, but without any extra options.

```
get-package
```